# Three.js Update Geometry Bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, three.js

I am creating an escape room with Three.js and React and I'm creating a timer that updates every second.
The timer was working fine until I added React to it and setInterval was running twice.
So to fix that, I decided to check the second in the date, and then check if the function has ran that second. If it hasn't, then it would run the function.
This part worked, and the seconds would update every second, but only in the variable.
The lines of code that I used to use to change the text does not work anymore.
Before that line, I console.log `12 : ${minutes_str} : ${seconds_str}` and that works properly.

```js
const time_geometry = new TextGeometry(`12 : ${minutes_str} : ${seconds_str}`, {
                    font: font,
                    size: 0.4,
                    height: 0.1,
                    curveSegments: 1,
                    bevelEnabled: true,
                    bevelThickness: 0.2,
                    bevelSize: 0.05,
                    bevelSegments: 5,
                });
                const time = scene.getObjectByName("time")
                time.geometry = time_geometry;
```

This is my whole code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // my scene properties
  // change time every second
    function changeTime(){
        var newSeconds = new Date().getSeconds();
        if (lastSecond != newSeconds){
            lastSecond = newSeconds
            loader.load('https://unpkg.com/three@0.77.0/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', (font) => {
                if (seconds == 59){
                    minutes += 1;
                    seconds = 0;
                } else {
                    seconds += 1;
                }
                if (seconds < 10){
                    seconds_str = "0" + seconds;
                } else {
                    seconds_str = seconds.toString();
                }
                if (minutes < 10){
                    minutes_str = "0" + minutes;
                } else {
                    minutes_str = minutes.toString()
                }
                console.log(`12 : ${minutes_str} : ${seconds_str}`)
                const time_geometry = new TextGeometry(`12 : ${minutes_str} : ${seconds_str}`, {
                    font: font,
                    size: 0.4,
                    height: 0.1,
                    curveSegments: 1,
                    bevelEnabled: true,
                    bevelThickness: 0.2,
                    bevelSize: 0.05,
                    bevelSegments: 5,
                });
                const time = scene.getObjectByName("time")
                time.geometry = time_geometry;
            })
        }
        
    }
    setInterval( changeTime, 1000);
  // checking the clicks, and double clicks
```

The clock mesh text is made by:

```js
loader.load('https://unpkg.com/three@0.77.0/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', (font) => {
      const time_geometry = new TextGeometry(`12 : ${minutes_str} : ${seconds_str}`, {
        font: font,
        size: 0.4,
        height: 0.1,
        curveSegments: 1,
        bevelEnabled: true,
        bevelThickness: 0.2,
        bevelSize: 0.05,
        bevelSegments: 5,
      });

      const text_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "black" } );
      const time = new THREE.Mesh(time_geometry, text_material);
      time.position.set(0.2,3.2, -4);
      time.name = 'time'
      scene.add(time);
});
```

Some extra info:

- This bug only happens when the modal is open at the start.
- If I save my work and the React updates, then the timer works
- But when I remove the modal, the clock still doesn't update

Can you figure out a way I can update the time on the clock every second (not twice every second)?